# Inserting array to database

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I use this code where it groups the question together with the choices.

```
<?php 

$entries = preg_split('/(?=[a-z\d]+\.(?!\d))/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); 

  $questions = array();
  $currentQuestion = null;
  $id = 0;

  foreach($entries as $entry) {
    if(is_numeric(substr($entry, 0, 1)) === true) {
        $currentQuestion = $entry;
        $questions[$entry] = array();
        $id++;
        // echo "INSERT INTO question (id, q_name) VALUES ($id, $currentQuestion)"."<br>";
        // mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO question (id, q_name) VALUES (NULL, '$currentQuestion')");
        continue;

    }

    // mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO answers (id, choices, question, correct) VALUES (NULL, 'choices', $id , 0);");
    // echo "INSERT INTO answers (id, choices, question, correct) VALUES (NULL, 'choices', $id , 'stuff')"."<br>";
    $questions[$currentQuestion][] = $entry;
  }
```

This is the result of the array.

```
Array
(
    [1. What is love?] => Array
        (
            [0] => a. Haddaway

            [1] => b. Haxxaway

            [2] => c. Hassaway

            [3] => d. Hannaway

        )

    [2. What is love? ] => Array
        (
            [0] => a. Haddaway

            [1] => b. Haxxaway

            [2] => c. Hassaway

            [3] => d. Hannaway

        )

    [3. What is love 1.1? ] => Array
        (
            [0] => a. Haddaway

            [1] => b. Haxxaway

            [2] => c. Hassaway

            [3] => d. Hannaway

        )

    [4. What is love? ] => Array
        (
            [0] => a. Haddaway

            [1] => b. Haxxaway

            [2] => c. Hassaway

            [3] => d. Hannaway 
        )

)
```

And this is my database structure: `question` column in table `answers` is the primary key from `questions` table, that will determine which question the choice belongs...

```
questions
+-------+--------------------------+
|  id   | q_name                   | 
+-------+--------------------------+
|   1   |   1.) What is foo?       |
|   2   |   2.) What is foo?       |
+-------+--------------------------+

answers
+-------+-------------+-----------------------+
|   id  | choices     |  question | correct   | 
+-------+-------------+-----------------------+
|   1   |   a. foo1   | 1         |   0       | 
|   2   |   b. foo2   | 1         |   0       |
|   3   |   c. foo3   | 1         |   1       |
|   4   |   a. foo3   | 2         |   0       |
|   5   |   b. foo2   | 2         |   1       |
|   6   |   c. foo1   | 2         |   0       |
+-------+-------------+-----------------------+
```

I managed to insert the questions to db but I'm having trouble to insert the choices because I'm confused on what I should do to `$questions` in order to get the choices...

Any suggestion(s) would do!

Comment: **1)** Try not to have a query running within a loop, but build it within the loop and execute it after the loop. **2)** Please can you paste the structure of your database tables; `answers ` and `questions` (`SHOW CREATE TABLE answers;`)?

Comment: Ohh, so sorry about that.. okay I will edit it, thanks a lot!

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I updated my question, I hope this is thorough enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would **not** use `json_encode()` for this as you're setting up a normalised data structure.

Here's a breakdown of what you need to do;

- Insert the question into `questions`
- Grab the `last_insert_id` and store it in a variable
- Insert the answers into `answers`
- Link the answers to the questions by using `last_insert_id`

Now onto the code.

**Collecting the data**

```
$arrAnswers = array();
$arrQuestions = array();
$id = 0; //Assuming your table is empty

foreach($entries as $entry) { //Loop through the grabbed records
  if(is_numeric(substr($entry, 0, 1)) === true) { //Is it a question?
     $id++;     
     $arrAnswers[$id] = array();
     $arrQuestions[$id] = '(\''. $entry .'\')'; 
  } else { //Ok, it's a possible answer to a question
     $arrAnswers[] = '(\''. $entry .'\', '. $id .', 0)';
  }
}
```

**Inserting the questions**

Now we have an array holding all the answers to a question. The array key will be the question id within the database. We can now insert the questions by doing;

```
$strDbQuery = "INSERT INTO `questions` (`q_name`) VALUES ". implode(", ", $arrQuestions);
// Execute the query.
```

**Inserting the answers**

Now you've inserted your questions, you can now insert your answers.

```
$strDbQuery = "INSERT INTO `answers` (`choices`, `question`, `correct`) VALUES ". implode(", ", $arrAnswers);
// Execute the query.
```

Because your array (in your question) didn't hold  a value to indicate whether or not an answer is correct or not, you'll have to do this manually.

Comment: Yes, I'll do something about to determine the answer is correct. I really appreciate your time for helping me! Kudos! I learn new things!

Comment: Hello again, I have an error on inserting answers to db, it says Array to String Conversion, I think this is happening since it's a multidimensional array?
this is what it returns...
INSERT INTO `answers` (`choices`, `question`, `correct`) VALUES Array

Comment: Hi @yowza - Just edited my answer so the answers are not in a multidimensional array :) So should be good.

Comment: Uhmm, hi again :D
how can I implode the answers in the loop?

Comment: You want to `implode` within the loop to do what? Execute the query? I wouldn't suggest you do. We're building an array of answers (with the question id they are for) as a string to build the final query. I'm unsure why you'd want to `implode` in the loop. Please explain.

Comment: Because I'm still not able to insert answers to db... and after some research, imploding the array answers could do it but you're explanation is thorough, I'm now confused. Sorry...

Answer (score 1):

To store an array, you'll need to write it as a string to the database. There are two (2) functions that come to mind:

`serialize()` [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)
`json_encode()` [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Either works great; `serialize()` will convert the array to a string which you can then save; to retrieve your array at a later time, pass the string to the `unserialize()` function.
`json_encode()` also has an accompanying `json_decode()` function. To read your data as an array [rather than an object in this scenario], you'll have to do this:
`$questions = json_decode($string_from_database, true);`

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'll look up on this! I'd like to extend my appreciation!

Comment: In my opinion, I guess json_encode() is appealing for me, I might need a second opinion!

Comment: @yowza you're right. It'll usually be smaller in size than `serialize()`

Comment: @yowza I would not use `json_encode()` for this. Although, Okeke may have answered before you updated your post to show your table design.